# SQL injection in pandas; binding list to params in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have this SQL query:

```
sql = "select * from table where date in {dl}"
```

where dl is a tuple of dates. I can do the query by doing `string.format(dl=...)` then using `read_sql_query` in pandas, but I read that this could lead to SQL injection and so isn't safe.

However, there doesn't seem to be a good alernative in SQLAlchemy. You can't seem to pass a list to the params using `text()`, and converting the list into a string first leads to an error. I see that you can iterate over the list and pass the parameters one by one, but why would anyone want to do that?

Would cleaning up the variable (removing quotes, semicolons, etc) help reduce the risk of SQL injection? Not being able to use a raw SQL string sounds like a terrible prospect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.bindparams()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.bindparams) to bind parameters to values in your `text()` construct:

```
sql = text("select * from table where date in :dl").bindparams(dl=...)
```

Note that the value you pass to `dl` has to be a tuple to be rendered correctly.

Comment: Thanks, this works for a tuple of dates. What if the param is a string? Would `bindparams` escape this properly and avoid the possibility of a SQL injection?

Comment: @tangfucius It's never actually escaped -- it's passed directly into the DBAPI `execute()` as parameters, **separate from the SQL**, which the database handles.

Comment: Great! That makes it totally safe then.